# Horrible performance when upgrading from node v6.7.0 to v8.11.1

Tags: node.js, performance, websocket, profiling, graphql

I have been spending the past few days investigating poor performance for an websocket graphql api application when upgrading node from v6.x to v8.x.

I have taken lots of flame graphs but I cannot figure out where the bottleneck is. Does anyone know what `___kdebug_trace_string` (in c++) is? It appears to be taking significantly more time in my application after the upgrade.

Check out this flame graph:

[image: Flame graph]

Also check out these profile logs:

node v8.x profile log (slow): 
https://pastebin.com/2W65BZC8

node v6.x profile log: 
https://pastebin.com/BL4kM7B7

Thanks ahead!

Comment: How about trying `node v9`? Also is it possible that the node is compiled with some debugging flags enabled by any chance?

Answer (score 6):

`kdebug_trace_string`  is a syscall that has been added to XNU in october 2015 for iOS 9 and OS X 10.11.

It's part of [kdebug](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Kdebug), the main XNU built-in debugging facility.
When reading [kdebug_trace.c](https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/master/libsyscall/wrappers/kdebug_trace.c), I found the following note in the comments :

> Note that the userspace API is chosing to optimize fastpath, non-error
> performance by eliding validation of each debugid. This means that
> error  cases which could have been caught in userspace will make a
> syscall  before returning with the correct error code. This tradeoff
> in   performance is intentional.

It explains why `___kdebug_trace_string` is taking so much place on your flame graph.

---

This is just a guess and all of this is wrong if you're not using an Apple computer, but then, if it's wrong, I really want to know what's causing this mess.

---

Assuming I'm right, if `kdebug_trace_string` is called, so it means that node runs some kind of debugging utility.
I downloaded *node-v8.11.1-darwin-x64*, and found the following line in `node/config.gypi` :

```
 'node_use_dtrace': 'true',
```

So node v8.11.1 uses dtrace. 
Then, looking at [this line](https://github.com/opendtrace/macos-dtrace/blob/master/libdtrace/dt_open.c#L432-L433) in `osx/src/dtrace/libdtrace/dt_open.c`, we can assume that dtrace uses `kdebug_trace_string`

So to fix this, one would want to prevent node from using dtrace. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023501/what-is-this-build-config-gypi-file-and-can-i-delete-it), " When Node starts up, the .gypi is loaded like any other settings file.". So maybe you should juste set `node_use_dtrace` to `false`

#### BUT

I don't understand why you didn't face the same problem with node v6.7.0 :

- In *node-v6.7.0-darwin-x64*, `node_use_dtrace` is set to `true` too
- Node v6.7 approx. release date :  2016-09-28
- OS X 10.11 approx release date :  2015-09-06

Could you tell me the value of `node_use_dtrace` for your two versions of node ?

Hope it helps, and hope I'm right,
Best regards

Comment: I believe the kdebug_trace_string is also showing up on ubuntu flamegraphs, but I will double check and post back tonight.

Comment: I am having problems creating flamegraphs in Ubuntu so I can not confirm that part. As for node_use_dtrace, it should be true for both versions, since profiling node on macOS uses dtrace.

Comment: Yes, but what if you turn off profiling in the config file ? Does it impact the performances ?